# 'Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined' when running Parse query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Whenever I run my Parse background job, it fails and I get the error below:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.b.Query._quote (Parse.js:3:14236)
    at Object.b.Query.contains (Parse.js:3:14337)
    at main.js:1491:40
    at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
    at Parse.js:2:4651
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:665)
    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:4602)
    at null.<anonymous> (Parse.js:2:5181)
    at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
```

This is the area causing the problem, line 1491 is the last line:

```
var MCI_Results = Parse.Object.extend("MCI_Results");



        var MCI_Results_Comparison_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);

        // Query for any MCI_Results that have new items

        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.equalTo('parent', parentUser);

        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.contains('searchTerm', searchTermsList[i]);

        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.containedIn('MCItems', top3List[i]);

        MCI_Results_Comparison_Query.find()

          .then(function(results) {

            //No new items                      

            if (results.length > 0) {

              console.log("No new items, you're good to go!");

              //Add user to the "DON'T send push notification" channel

              ////////

              var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

              installationQuery.equalTo('userId', parentUser);


              installationQuery.first()

                .then(function(result) {

                  result.set('channels', ["noPush"]);

                  result.save();

                });

              ///////

              console.log('done updating channel');

            }

            //New items found

            else if (results.length === 0) {

              console.log('no matching MCI_Results, lets push some new shit');

              console.log('searchTermsList[i]:' + searchTermsList[i]);



              var MCI_Results_Update_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);

              MCI_Results_Update_Query.equalTo('parent', parentUser);

              MCI_Results_Update_Query.contains('searchTerm', searchTermsList[i]);
```

All I'm doing here is setting the parameters for a query, there's no replace method involved at all. What's causing it to state that as the error? I triple checked, and I'm positive searchTermsList[i] exists, and the searchTerm property on the MCI_Results object also exists.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

For me the "fix" (I guess "workaround" is more accurate) was to avoid "contains" and use "containedIn" instead. It's not intuitive that it should work, but it seems to do the trick.

I guess that, when it comes to arrays, neither of those two methods are really the set operations that their names suggest, but that they simply look for overlap and thus there is no difference between contains and containedIn?